# Why are the items in my listview box all cramped together?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm just trying to display some data in a listview box on Microsoft Visual Studio but whenever I do it's all jumbled together and cramped up. When I did small and big font it was the same result and I'm not sure how exactly to fix it.

This is the display code that I have:

```
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Number of Salaried Employees: " + salariedEmployees);
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Annual Pay for Salaried Employees");
//ADD MORE
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("---------------------------------------------");
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Number of Waged Employees: " + wagedEmployees);
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Annual Pay for Waged Employees");
//ADD MORE
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("---------------------------------------------");
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("---------------------------------------------");
```

and this is what it turns out to be:

[image: Image of cramped up listview]

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: This doesn't look like a good fit for the ListView control.  Would a DataGridView be better?  Or a simple readonly multiline TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment by LarsTech. That said, yes I believe I do  "know why this is happening and how to fix it". Unless you change it in the form designer, the default value for `lvwPayroll.View` is probably `LargeIcon`. What you are seeing is likely a rendering of 7 *icons* (one for each `Item`) that *don't* have an image, but *do* have a very long title that's being squashed into the narrow width of the icon's rectangle.

---

Try setting the `View` property to `List`.

```
lvwPayroll.View = View.List;

lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Number of Salaried Employees: " + salariedEmployees);
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Annual Pay for Salaried Employees");
//ADD MORE
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("---------------------------------------------");
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Number of Waged Employees: " + wagedEmployees);
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("Total Annual Pay for Waged Employees");
//ADD MORE
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("---------------------------------------------");
lvwPayroll.Items.Add("---------------------------------------------");
```

[image: screenshot]